# Ubuntu 22.04. getting operation not permitted when tries to copy a password protected pdf file with sudo

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, ssh, pdf

I'm having a ubuntu 22.04 server. I copied a password protected pdf file to user home directory via scp and then tried to copy the same pdf in to same directory with another name.

eg: `sudo cp A1.pdf _A1.pdf`

I'm getting

```
cp: cannot open 'A1.pdf' for reading. Operation not permitted error.
```

But I can do the same thing in another server which run ubuntu 20.04.

what prevents me from copying the file in 22.04?

```
ubuntu@ip-10-xxx-xxx-xx:~$ lsattr A2.pdf
lsattr: Operation not permitted While reading flags on A2.pd
```

```
ubuntu@ip-10-xxx-xxx-xx:~$lsof A2.pdf     # (returned empty) 
ubuntu@ip-10-xxx-xxx-xx:~$
```

```
ubuntu@ip-10-xxx-xxx-xx:~$ file A2.pdf 
A2.pdf: writable, regular file, no read permission
```

```
ubuntu@ip-10-xxx-xxx-xx:~$ ls A2.pdf -al
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1354946 Dec 27 06:36 A2.pdf
```

Comment: What is the output of `lsattr A1.pdf` and of `lsof A1.pdf` and of `file A1.pdf` ... Of course those commands need to be run after changing directory to where that file is located i.e. "user home directory"

Comment: That's getting a bit interesting ... What filesystem (EXT*, FAT*, NTFS ...etc.) is the user's home directory on? Is it on a separate mount? How do you mount it? Do you run any kind of antivirus or any monitoring app like it on that system? and please run `sudo lsattr A1.pdf` with sudo again and see if it returns anything.

Comment: File system is ext4, is the root drive not a separate mount. Not running any antivirus, installed nginx, php-fpm, redis, mysql-client. 'sudo lsattr A1.pdf' also returned the same error.

Comment: I have setup a new server with ubuntu 22.04 in aws and tried the same.. in that I can copy the file.  So not sure what causing the issue in my old server.

Comment: A filesystem out of inodes might exhibit similar behavior, so check with `df -i /` and a filesystem-level encryption will also show similar behavior so is there implemented such encryption affecting the user's home?

Comment: @Raffa. I have narrows it down to the reason. I have noticed there is log entry in syslog regarding McAfee. I didn't install any antivirus but McAfee is running. [Refering[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70627418/unable-to-open-boot-vmlinuz-5-x-x-x-generic-dpkg-new-operation-not-permitted) question, I stopped the service and tried copying the pdf file. it WORKED. I'm not sure why McAfee is preventing the copy functionality.. I have started the McAfee service back again because i'm not sure what will happen if i stopped it.